# After a Git merge conflict, a lot of new files to be committed

Tags: git

Once I created a branch from dev and added some functionality.
Now I created merge request and have a merge conflicts.
What I do: I pull changes from dev branch and have conflict in one file(I resolved it), but also I have many new files. So if I commit them and push, I will have many changes in my MR, how can I avoid it?

Comment: this new files in dev branch you don‘t want to merge?

Answer (score 2):

This will help you to resolve this problem or learn something

- Once you created a "feature" branch from "dev" branch using checkout, the feature branch will get all content from dev

`(dev) $ git checkout -b dev feature`

- But when parallelly feature and dev branches will develop. Then you
  try to merge the feature branch into the dev branch from dev branch.

`(dev) $ git merge feature -m "Merge feature into Dev"`

- This can have conflicts, because of merge process try to merge all feature changes into dev branch.
- **So You can use file path specific merge**

`(dev) $ git checkout feature <specific file pathe "src/main/webapp/index.html">`

- This will collect changes from the only specified file in feature branch to dev branch and you can see them as a modification. then you
  can commit them

`(dev) $ git commit -m "Merge index.html from feature"`